# Regex searching rows in CSV for characters getting hung up on first match

Tags: regex, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am newer to scripting, so my code may be a bit mangled, I apologize in advance.

I am trying to iterate through a CSV and write it to an excel workbook using openpyxl. But before I write it, I am performing a few checks to determine which sheet to write the row to.

The row has content such as:"KB4462941", "kb/9191919", "kb   -919", "sdfklKB91919".

I am trying to pull the first numbers following "KB" then stop reading in characters once a non-numeric character is found. One I find it, then I run a separate function that queries a DB. That function works.

The problem I am running into, is once it finds the first KB: KB4462941, it gets hung up and goes over that KB multiple times until the last time it appears in that row, then the program finishes.

Unfortunately, there is not default location for where the KB characters will be in the row, and there is no default character count between the KB and the first numbers.

My code:

```
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if str(row).find("SSL") != -1:
            ws = book.get_sheet_by_name('SSL')
            ws.append(row)
        else:
            mylist = list(row)
            string = ''.join(mylist)
            tmplist = list()
            resultlist = list()
            pattern = 'KB.*[0-9]*'
            for i in mylist:
                tmplist += re.findall(pattern, i, re.IGNORECASE)
            for i in tmplist:
                resultlist += re.findall('[0-9]*', i)
            for i in resultlist:
                if len(i) > 4:
                    print i
                    if dbFunction(i) == 1:
                        ws = book.get_sheet_by_name('Found')
                        ws.append(row)
                else:
                    ws = book.get_sheet_by_name('Nothing')
                    ws.append(row)

output: 
1st row is skipped
2nd row is in the right place
3rd and 4th row in the right place
5th row is written for the next nine 9 rows.
never gets to the following 3 rows.
```

Comment: Change pattern = `'KB.*[0-9]*'` to `pattern = 'KB.*?[0-9]+'` You need a non greedy pattern between KB and the first digit and at least one digit

Comment: Could you please provide an example test.csv file?